# Eigenvalues of large symmetric matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, adjacency-matrix, eigenvalue

When I try to compute the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of [a very large graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3ytliwfcgsdgul/c500.m?dl=0) I get, what can be charitably described as, garbage. In particular, since the graph is four-regular, the eigenvalues should be in $[-4, 4]$ but they are visibly not. I used Matlab (via MATLink), and got the same problems, so this is clearly an issue that transcends mathematica. The question is: what is the best way to deal with it? I am sure MATLAB and Mathematica use the venerable EISPAK code, so there may be something newer/better

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the question trivial?

Comment: Can you post code to convert this graph to the (sparse?) adjacency matrix? Matlab’s `eigs` uses ARPACK.

Comment: @AhmedFasih I am not sure which sparse matrix format you prefer; would a list of (i, j, val) be good?

Comment: Ah, rereading your question, I see that you called Matlab thru a Mathematica link. I thought you had regenerated your adjacency graph in Matlab… it has its own [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) data structure, and its algorithms run with it. If it’s straightforward to make code that regenerates the matrix, that’d be helpful for others to test.

Comment: Could this be caused by `Infinity` being a node? Not sure how smart Mathematica or MatLink are, if they can treat the node’s numeric label as just a label, or if they try to use it as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalue methods for dense matrices usually proceed by first transforming the matrix into Hessenberg form, here this would result in a tridiagonal matrix. After that some variant of the shifted QR algorithm, like bulge-chasing, is applied to iteratively reduce the non-diagonal elements, splitting the matrix at positions where these become small enough.

But what I would like to draw the attention to is that first step and its structure destroying consequences. It is, for instance, not guaranteed that the tri-diagonal matrix is still symmetrical. This applies also to all further steps if they are not explicitly tailored for symmetric matrices.

But what is much more relevant here is that this step ignores all connectivity or non-connectivity of the graph and potentially connects all nodes, albeit with very small weights, when the transformation is reversed.

Each of the `m` connected component of the graph gives one eigenvalue 4 with an eigenvector that is 1 at the nodes of the components and 0 else. These eigenspaces have all dimension 1. Any small perturbation of the matrix first removes that separation and joins them in an eigenspace of dimension `m` and then perturbs this as a multiple eigenvalue. This then can result in an approximately regular `m` pointed star in the complex plane of radius `4*(1e-15)^(1/m)` around the original value 4. Even for medium sized `m` this gives a substantial deviation from the true eigenvalue.

---

So in summary, use a sparse method as these usually will first re-order the matrix to be as diagonal as possible, which should give a block-diagonal structure according to the components. Then the eigenvalue method will automatically work on all blocks separately, avoiding the above described mixing. And if possible, use a method for symmetric matrices or set a corresponding option/flag if it exists.